# Batch file going straight through commands

Tags: batch-file

Basically, I have a question set up and if I answer "interrupt," it SHOULD say "You decide to finally walk over there...," and under that, "How will the man react?" Then, it SHOULD generate a random number from 1-21 and then pause. However, when I answer "interrupt," it closes the program. Although, when I remove the random number generator, it works pauses after "How will the man react?" and I can exit. What's wrong with the number generator being there?

Here's the code:

```
echo Do you interrupt or wait until they are finished talking?
echo.
set /p choice=
if %choice%==interrupt (
  echo You decide to finally walk over there. You ask the man who is telling the story, "So what's in the labyrinth?"
  echo How does the man react?
  pause
  set /a num=((20 + 1) * %random%) / 32768 + 1
  echo %num%
  pause
  exit
)
```

Thank you all for reading and/or replying!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read variables with changed values inside a code block you always need `delayed expansion` and `!variables!` instead of `%variables%`. Moreover, the `for` loop parser reads all closing parentheses `)`  inside the code block and wants to end the block. You should escape this parentheses with a `^`caret or double quotes.

Comment: that means the `echo`-line. I've overseen that ^^

Answer (score 2):

you will have to escape the closing `)`

replace

```
set /a num=((20 + 1) * %random%) / 32768 + 1
```

with

```
set /a num=((20 + 1^) * %random%^) / 32768 + 1
```

Comment: I have inserted the carrots, however, it's not giving me an answer. I turned echo on to look at it, and it's not even calculating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around the equation like this

```
set /a num="((20 + 1) * %random%) / 32768 + 1"
```

or this

```
set /a "num=((20 + 1) * %random%) / 32768 + 1"
```

or as Stephan said, you can also escape the closing brackets `)`.

Also, if you want to use `%num%` inside the `if "%choice%"=="interrupt" (...)` block, you have to use delayed expansion, like Endoro said.

To improve your code, you should also put quotes around the choice like above before comparing it to prevent spaces in `%choice%` messing with the code.

Comment: `if [%choice%]==[interrupt]` should be `if "%choice%"=="interrupt"` to protect against spaces and other poison characters.

Answer (score 0):

A method that doesn't need escaping ( or using delayed expansion is below, and also note the case insensitive check for 'interrupt'.

```
echo Do you interrupt or wait until they are finished talking?
echo.
set /p choice=
if /i not "%choice%"=="interrupt" goto :skip001
  echo You decide to finally walk over there. You ask the man who is telling the story, "So what's in the labyrinth?"
  echo How does the man react?
  pause
  set /a num=((20 + 1) * %random%) / 32768 + 1
  echo %num%
  pause
  exit
:skip001
```